# How to specify the schema for array of JSONs for IntelliSense

Tags: json, visual-studio, jsonschema

For adding IntelliSense feature for JSON, I created a JSON schema for an array of JSON objects. I manually validated the schema for the JSON by adding the schema to the dropdown in Visual Studio below

[image]

Now how can I save this as a config so anyone who uses this file in my project is able to use the schema? I tried $schema property

```
"$schema" = "MySchema.json"
```

but the root of my JSON file is an array so I was not able to use it. I cannot change the root of an element. Any suggestion on how I can define the schema to the JSON? Below is my Schema file and my JSON file.

MySchema.json :

```
{
  "type": "array",
  "items": {
    "type": "Object",
    "properties": {
      "item1": {
        "type": [ "string" ]
      },
      "item2": {
        "type": [ "string" ],
        "enum": [ "hey" ]
      },
      "item3": {
        "type": [ "string" ],
        "enum": [ "hi", "hello" ]
      }
    },
    "required": [ "item1", "item2", "item3" ]
  }    
}
```

MyJson.json :

```
 [
   {
     "item1": "abc",
     "item2": "hey",
     "item3": "hello"
   },
   {
     "item1": "def",
     "item2": "hey",
     "item3": "hi"
   }
 ]
```

The goal here is to create IntelliSense feature for an existing JSON. Please suggest if there are any alternate approaches as well.

Answer (score 0):

A couple small issues with your schema which I fixed below.

`type` values must always be lowercase

you can find more information about how JSON Schemas are defined [Understanding JSON Schema](https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/)

adding `title` and `description` will help with the intellisense

```json
{
    "$id": "https://www.example.com/schemas/myCustomSchema",
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
    "title": "my custom schema",
    "description": "A custom schema for my own purpose",
    "type": "array",
    "minItems": 1,
    "items": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
            "item1": {
                "title": "Item1",
                "description": "This is item1",
                "type": "string"
            },
            "item2": {
                "title": "Item2",
                "description": "This is item2",
                "type": "string",
                "enum": ["hey"]
            },
            "item3": {
                "title": "Item3",
                "description": "This is item3",
                "type": "string",
                "enum": [
                    "hi",
                    "hello"
                ]
            }
        },
        "required": ["item1", "item2", "item3"],
        "additionalProperties": false
    }
}
```

Save your custom schema to the same project or you can enter a url in the `schema` dropdown menu to point to a hosted location. Once you apply the schema to the document, Visual Studio should save it in your project settings so anyone can use the schema going forward when they open the file.

I don't have a running copy of Visual Studio to give an example.

**bonus content**: *If you're using VS Code, you need to add it to your `settings.json`*

```json
"json.schemas": [
    {
        "fileMatch": [
            "/*.myCustomSchema.json"  // this is a glob pattern to match a specific file naming convention for VSC to pickup the proper schema
        ],
        "url": "file:/Users/fieljere/Downloads/myCustomSchema.json" //  this is a location to retrieve the schema. On local, you can use the `file` protocol.
    }
]
```

```json
#jeremy.myCustomSchema.json

[
    {
        "item1": "item1",
        "item2": "hey",
        "item3": "hello"
    }
]
```

[image: custom schema]