# How to get rid of the warning in file "cmake-kits.json"?

Tags: warnings, vscode-extensions, jsonschema

I am writing my extension that offers you some cmake-kits. In file package.json I have:

```
    "contributes": {
...
        "jsonValidation": [
            {
                "fileMatch": "cmake-kits.json",
                "url": "./cmake-kits_schema.json"
            }
        ]
...
    },
```

In file cmake-kits_schema.json:

```
{
    "definitions": {
        "kit1": {
            "type": "object",
            "defaultSnippets": [
                {
                    "label": "Label1",
                    "body": {
                        "name": "name1",
                        "toolchainFile": "file1",
                        "environmentVariables": "var1"
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        "kit2": {
            "type": "object",
            "defaultSnippets": [
                {
                    "label": "Label2",
                    "body": {
                        "name": "name2",
                        "toolchainFile": "file2",
                        "environmentVariables": "var2"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "type": "array",
    "items": {
        "anyOf": [
            {
                "type": "object"
            },
            {
                "$ref": "#/definitions/kit1"
            },
            {
                "$ref": "#/definitions/kit2"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

And when I run my extension and go to file `cmake-kits_schema.json` I got warning. I also noticed that when I disable extension `CMake Tools`, warning goes away. How to fix it?

I tried to fix it, but actually I didn't find any helpful pieces of advice.

```
Problems loading reference 'schemaservice://combinedschema/cmake-tools-schema:/schemas/kits-schema.json': Unable to load schema from 'schemaservice://combinedschema/cmake-tools-schema:/schemas/kits-schema.json': cannot open schemaservice://combinedschema/cmake-tools-schema%3A/schemas/kits-schema.json. Detail: Unable to resolve resource schemaservice://combinedschema/cmake-tools-schema%3A/schemas/kits-schema.json.
```

Comment: are you hosting the schema file locally?  It's trying to pull the schema from `./` as the base url.  if you're hosting it locally.. use the `file` protocol. `file://path/to/file.cmake.json`

there's an example of that here. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77131419/how-to-specify-the-schema-for-array-of-jsons-for-intellisense/77134747#77134747

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify your schema quite a bit. if all of your `definitions` are `type: object`, having `"anyOf": [{"type": "object"}]` is redundant. Your `kit` and `kit2` are also the same structure, no need to duplicate it.

```json
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
    "title": "cmakeType",
    "description": "A c-make representation",
    "type": "array",
    "uniqueItems": true,
    "items": {
        "$ref": "#/definitions/kit1"
    },
    "definitions": {
        "kit1": {
            "type": "object",
            "defaultSnippets": {
                "type": "array",
                "items": {
                    "type": "object",
                    "properties": {
                        "label": {
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        "body": {
                            "$ref": "#/defintions/body"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "body": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "name": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "toolchainFile": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "environmentVariables": {
                    "type": "string"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

find more info on how to structure JSON Schemas at [Understanding JSON Schema](https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/)